# Prevent application from running on a particular browser

Tags: gwt

When I build a GWT application, it runs on all browsers like IE,chrome,firefox etc. provided GWT plugin is installed for that browser.
I want to know how can I prevent a GWT application from running on a particular browser i.e. if I don't want my GWT apps to run on say Firefox, how can I achieve that? What changes I need to do in my code?

Comment: Seriously, why would you do that?? Closest you could come, IMO, is by checking the `User-Agent` Header, and branching off from your usual logic.

Comment: don't understand why people voted down to this question? is it not a valid one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,ie8,ie9,safari,opera" />` to your `*.gwt.xml` file and it will fail to load in Firefox (FYI, Firefox's `user.agent` token is `gecko1_8`).

If you don't want to support IE6 and IE7 for instance, you don't need to compile for them, and you can decrease your compilation time by removing the `ie6` token from the `user.agent` value list.